# Getting SOAP Error when connecting Drupal to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I've created a Drupal7 module to extract the data from Salesforce

The idea is that I should be able to run a SOQL query and load this into an array.

I'm getting an error message saying
"SOAP Error Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'soapclient/partner.wsdl.xml'

failed to load external entity "soapclient/partner.wsdl.xml" in SoapClient->SoapClient()

I've checked the path and confirm this is pointing to the correct file.

Here is my code

```
define("USERNAME", "salesforce@decawave.com");
define("PASSWORD", "Decawave3");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "MfNG8OgO06l4hVWFpi0MjDMeN");
require_once ('soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');

$connection = new SforcePartnerClient();
$connection->createConnection("soapclient/partner.wsdl.xml");
$connection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

$query = "SELECT Name FROM TREK__c";
$result = $Connection->query($query);

foreach($result as $record)
{
$id[] = $record->Name;
}
```

Comment: I'm not good at PHP, but what is createConnection("soapclient/partner.wsdl.xml"); ?

Comment: createConnection is a method of the SForcePartnerClient Class

Comment: it's worth mentioning that I have a PHP file that does the same and is working.

Comment: And what is the difference between these two files?

Comment: $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
    $mySforceConnection->createConnection("soapclient/partner.wsdl.xml");
    $mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME,    PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

$query = "SELECT Name FROM TREK__c";
$result = $mySforceConnection->query($query);